# Managing jobs on remote computers running Windows

Tags: windows-xp, desktop, remote

I have 10 computers at work all of which have Windows XP (either 32- or 64-bit).  Each installation is a separate one and not server-based.  I work on different sets of code and to run jobs I have set up batch scripts for each which can take command line arguments.

Now to run any job, I login on the remote computer (via Remote Desktop) and execute it on the command line.  I have no way to queue another process since if I overload the processors (i.e. jobs > processors) the run-time on each job takes a huge hit.  The Remote Desktop approach is proving to be a huge bottleneck since that means the computers are sitting idle unless I login to check the progress etc. (which can be for long if, for example, I am working on some code development).

Can you suggest any software which will help me in this system?  I have tried "psexec" but it does not work properly in the interactive mode.  PlatformLSF is very very expensive.  The only other software I think may meet my needs is Visualcron (plus its inexpensive) but not so sure about it.  Any thoughts on Visualcron?

Answer (score 1):

Powershell and/or VBScript can do what you need, and are free, but will require some coding.  It's fairly trivial to set up a VBScript to run remote commands (a quick google search will turn up a lot of hits, check for "vbscript execute remote command").

What I normally do with VBScript when I want to make a "Queue" is to use indicator files, and set up a loop to watch for those files to exist before executing.  If you like I can post links to some instructional sites to get started.

For software specifically for this purpose, you may be better off asking on [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: Apologies if this was the wrong forum to post such a question.  I will post the same on serverfault.com and see what people have to say for that.  Thanks for the pointer.
Unfortunately, my knowledge of VBScript is non-existent and am not sure how easy it would be to queue jobs etc.  That being said, I am combing through the results and have started to play with VBScript to see if I can tailor it for my needs.

Comment: I don't think it was WRONG, but you may get a better response from the other folks since this is their area of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [VisualCron](http://www.visualcron.com) as well. The latest version also have options to wait for completions of remote process.